# Crystal report one field from database and format it in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have only one field in a table which i am using in crystal report in details section.
now i want that field as **word wrap** as it is too big and i want it one after another.

i.e

if i am having a field say **"address"** in details section

and i am placing it at left side i want the field to be printed next record next to it and then next record next to it going from **"left to right"** and after the page border is end next record should be printed again from left to right and so on

and i am using VS 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that field is in your `details section`, do a right click on the `details section` and go to `section expert`, search for `Format with Multiple Columns` and check it. Then a `layout` tab will appears, so go there and select `across then down`. You can also adjust width and height there.